# DC.JS BarChart with a target red line

Tags: javascript, charts, dc.js

Im trying to add a a horizontal target line on my barchart but I could not add it folllowing the examples I follow.

there is a default y line in the html `<line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6"></line>`it correspond to the default y axis values and if in the inspector of the browser in the html y change x2 value to 300 (for instance) Y got what i want but dont know where to doit in the code, because ITS a :nth-child(8) in the DOM

I supuse that it should be an easy task but was not able to do it.

I would appreciate if anybody can guide me to a solution.

this is my js code

```
var monthChart = dc.barChart('#monthChart');

d3.csv('indisp.csv').then(data2 =>{
   const monthformat = '%m';
    data2.forEach(d => {
      d.disp = +d.disp *100 ;
    });
    console.log(data2)
    var ndx       = crossfilter(data2);
    
    var dispDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.MONTH;})
    
    var dispGroup       = dispDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.disp;});

    monthChart
      .width(404)
      .height(250)
      .x(d3.scaleBand())
      .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
      .y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([99.01, 100]))
      .brushOn(false)
      .xAxisLabel('Fruit')
      .yAxisLabel('Quantity Sold')
      .dimension(dispDim)
      .barPadding(0.2)
      .outerPadding(0.25)
      .group(dispGroup)
      

    dc.renderAll();
  });
```

Comment: You can try using composite charts in dc.js. What I see here you want to draw a target line which runs parallel to the x-axis. One way is you can stack two charts using composite chart. This will help you to add a layer over existing maps. If you can share your code  on code pen or something, I can help

Comment: [This example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/bar-extra-line.html) adds an extra line; it's like @gherka's solution below, but it uses the scales so that you can use domain coordinates. If you want the extra line to appear first, you can use `pretransition` instead of `renderlet`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a basic reference line in a fixed position, you can simply append a line to your SVG after it's been rendered by DC. Here's a JSFiddle with a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c08ymbjn/4/), but the relevant part of the code is this:

```
barChart.on("renderlet", function(chart) {
  
  chart.select(".chart-body")
    .append("line")
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', 110)
    .attr('x2', 300)
    .attr('y2', 110)
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1);

});
```

If your Y-axis is likely to change, you will need to fiddle around with scales so that the line's y1 and y2 values are tied to whatever range you have.